# How to track mouse movement without crashing server

Tags: javascript, analytics

I've been tasked with developing metrics for how users interact with our web portal. A coworker suggested that I look into "heat maps" to monitor user mouse position. This idea seemed cool to me. It seems there are already some SaaS solutions, but our budget is thin, so I whipped up some javascript:

```
class UserLog {
  constructor(){
    // ...
    this.results = {... mouseMovements=[]}
  }
  /* ... more functions ... */

  trackMouseMovement(){
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
      this.results.mouseMovements.push({
        timestamp: Date.now(),
        x: event.pageX,
        y: event.pageY
      });
    });
  }
}
```

I am currently using a timer to send this array to my server every 10 seconds:

```
window.setInterval(() => {
  $.ajax({
    url: endpoint, 
    type: "POST",
    data: this.results,
  });
},10*1000);
```

I'm running into the `mouseMovements` array can get up to several hundred elements in length and makes my browser cry when the ajax executes.

I can try sending data more frequently, or I can try preprocessing the `mouseMovements` array:

```
preprocessData: results =>{
    const newResults= {
      ...results,
      mouseMovements: results.mouseMovements.filter((val, index) => index % 10 == 0)
    }
    return newResults
  }
```

(1) How do people implement a mouse tracking protocol that allows the user's machine to operate as usual and provides enough resolution on the back end to playback the user's session and understand how to improve their experience on the site?

(2) How often should I be sending the ajax requests to my server? I am looking at some major sites and noticing that their requests seem to be click-driven. Is tracking mouse movements and scrolls not optimal? Or is there a better way of collecting this information?

Comment: is there a reason you need to track mousemove ? is that event part of the interaction? compared to clicks, mousedown events etc?

Comment: I'm the only developer on this site. I am very comfortable with backend and data analysis, but I'm absolutely terrified I'm going to bungle the front-end and want to have all the tools at my disposal when I inevitably have to debug user tickets

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to throttle your API request, most of the collaborating products like the `Figma` design tool, in which you can see other people's mouse position in real-time, most likely sends mouse position once in `600ms`.

`600ms` is janky, but if you think of mouse positions as `keyframes`, then you can animate between two mouse positions, so the user will always see smooth mouse movement, of course it depends on your animation algorithm.

Comment: I hadn't considered animating the missing frames. Great idea! What's the rationale behind throttling the API?  DOS attacks?

Comment: Because mouse movement event occurs really fast!
It will crush the server easily.